# why this php code works?

Tags: php

what is "_" in php, and why it's a valid function when it's not defined.

```
# code will pass that check. and it will print "_"
if(function_exists("_"))
{
    print f('_');
}
```

also when i try to print ( it works, but gives me Notice )

```
print _;
```

php give me Notice.

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant _ - assumed '_'
```

so i used constant function and try to get his value,

```
print constant("_");
```

but what i get is

```
Warning: constant() [function.constant]: Couldn't find constant _ in
```

what i'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Also, with php.net, you can go to www.php.net/{any built-in function/class} and it will show you the docs for that function. If it is not found, it will search the php docs for that function. for example: http://www.php.net/_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_` function is a shortcut for [gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php), a translation function. `http://php.net/_`

`print _;` prints the constant `_`, while `print _();` would show you the output of the _ function (an error, when called with no arguments).

Comment: Could you give some more explanation what this function does?

Comment: @Martinsos The docs are quite clear.

Answer (score 3):

Because _() is a valid function,

It is used for localization.

when you just print `_` you are trying to print the constant, adding the brackets `()` makes it a function call.

Your `function_exists` check should have told you that!

http://www.php.net/_